# Codeless kext to force a specific driver (CDC-ACM)

Tags: macos, serial-port, modem, cdc, kernel-extension

I'm wondering if there is a way to use a USB Modem (of Huawei E1550 species) on OS X in a generic manner, like a generic USB modem. The problem is that the OS won't recognise it as a legitimate CDC ACM device (which it is, but it doesn't advertise being such).

On Linux, the dongle is automatically recognised as a USB serial device.

There are reasons I don't want neither ZTE nor Huawei vendor drivers on any of my machines: these folks write stuff that barely works (my last experience with ZTE drivers involved spamming my logs, hogging the RAM, and me being unable to disable that), their drivers are not forward-compatible, they neglect to sync them with newer OS version, and they generally intend to distribute those drivers with carrier bloatware.

Apple's developer documentation writes in a vague way that a codeless kext can be written to force a specific driver on a matching device, or prevent a generic driver to load for a matching device. In fact, most searches on codeless kexts yield questions like "how do I prevent my serial dongle to be recognised as a modem?", while what I want is totally opposite!

My tries at writing such a codeless kext so far ended in a fiasco — kextutil tells the kext is loaded successfully, however it's not there, and so is AppleCDCACM.kext (which has the IOClass I want to use).

JFYI, the lsusb information as gathered from Linux:

```
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x12d1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
  idProduct          0x1001 E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
  bcdDevice            0.00
  iManufacturer           2 HUAWEI Technology
  iProduct                1 HUAWEI Mobile
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           85
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          3 Qualcomm Configuration
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               5
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval              32
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval              32
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval              32
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval              32
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval              32
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval              32
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

The interface I want to hook up is interface 0 (modem).

Here's how `ioreg` sees it:

```
   | |   |       | | +-o HUAWEI Mobile@1d110000  
    | |   |       | |   +-o AppleUSBHostLegacyClient  
    | |   |       | |   +-o AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice  
    | |   |       | |   +-o IOUSBHostInterface@0  
    | |   |       | |   |   {
    | |   |       | |   |     "USBPortType" = 0
    | |   |       | |   |     "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"2d9786c6-9ef3-11d4-ad51-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
    | |   |       | |   |     "bcdDevice" = 0
    | |   |       | |   |     "USBSpeed" = 3
    | |   |       | |   |     "idProduct" = 4097
    | |   |       | |   |     "bConfigurationValue" = 1
    | |   |       | |   |     "bInterfaceSubClass" = 255
    | |   |       | |   |     "locationID" = 487653376
    | |   |       | |   |     "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
    | |   |       | |   |     "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBInterface"
    | |   |       | |   |     "AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID" = 4294969542
    | |   |       | |   |     "idVendor" = 4817
    | |   |       | |   |     "bInterfaceProtocol" = 255
    | |   |       | |   |     "bAlternateSetting" = 0
    | |   |       | |   |     "bInterfaceNumber" = 0
    | |   |       | |   |     "bInterfaceClass" = 255
    | |   |       | |   |   }
    | |   |       | |   |   
    | |   |       | |   +-o IOUSBHostInterface@1  
    | |   |       | |   |   {
    | |   |       | |   |     "USBPortType" = 0
    | |   |       | |   |     "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"2d9786c6-9ef3-11d4-ad51-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
    | |   |       | |   |     "bcdDevice" = 0
    | |   |       | |   |     "USBSpeed" = 3
    | |   |       | |   |     "idProduct" = 4097
    | |   |       | |   |     "bConfigurationValue" = 1
    | |   |       | |   |     "bInterfaceSubClass" = 255
    | |   |       | |   |     "locationID" = 487653376
    | |   |       | |   |     "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
    | |   |       | |   |     "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBInterface"
    | |   |       | |   |     "AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID" = 4294969544
    | |   |       | |   |     "idVendor" = 4817
    | |   |       | |   |     "bInterfaceProtocol" = 255
    | |   |       | |   |     "bAlternateSetting" = 0
    | |   |       | |   |     "bInterfaceNumber" = 1
    | |   |       | |   |     "bInterfaceClass" = 255
    | |   |       | |   |   }
    | |   |       | |   |   
    | |   |       | |   +-o IOUSBHostInterface@2  
    | |   |       | |       {
    | |   |       | |         "USBPortType" = 0
    | |   |       | |         "IOCFPlugInTypes" = {"2d9786c6-9ef3-11d4-ad51-000a27052861"="IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle"}
    | |   |       | |         "bcdDevice" = 0
    | |   |       | |         "USBSpeed" = 3
    | |   |       | |         "idProduct" = 4097
    | |   |       | |         "bConfigurationValue" = 1
    | |   |       | |         "bInterfaceSubClass" = 255
    | |   |       | |         "locationID" = 487653376
    | |   |       | |         "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
    | |   |       | |         "IOClassNameOverride" = "IOUSBInterface"
    | |   |       | |         "AppleUSBAlternateServiceRegistryID" = 4294969546
    | |   |       | |         "idVendor" = 4817
    | |   |       | |         "bInterfaceProtocol" = 255
    | |   |       | |         "bAlternateSetting" = 0
    | |   |       | |         "bInterfaceNumber" = 2
    | |   |       | |         "bInterfaceClass" = 255
    | |   |       | |       }
    | |   |       | |
```

So far, the Info.plist looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>15C27b</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>name.fedevych.GenericWWAN</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>GenericWWAN</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>99.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacOSX</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>99.0.0</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>HUAWEI_0x12d11001_Control</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>AppleUSBACMControl</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBHostInterface</string>

            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer>4817</integer>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <integer>4097</integer>
            <key>bcdDevice</key>
            <integer>0</integer>

            <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
            <integer>1</integer>

            <key>IOMatchCategory</key>
            <string>com.apple.driver.AppleUSBACMControl</string>
        </dict>
        <key>HUAWEI_0x12d11001_Data</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>AppleUSBACMData</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBHostInterface</string>

            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer>4817</integer>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <integer>4097</integer>
            <key>bcdDevice</key>
            <integer>0</integer>

            <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
            <integer>1</integer>

        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>OSBundleLibraries</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I can't guarantee you success with your project - I have no idea if your modem will work with the standard CDC driver. But I can hopefully help you find out. There are 5 parts to this really:

1. The correct matching dictionary to match the device/interface in question.
2. Setting up the correct class and bundle ID for the actual driver.
3. Some extra points to watch out for in the info.plist of a codeless kext
4. Kext signing.
5. Loading/Debugging.

**I/O Kit USB matching**

Apple's [Q&A QA1076](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1076/_index.html) is the best resource on the topic. I'd recommend being as specific as possible. So in your case, for example:

```
IOProviderClass: IOUSBInterface
idVendor: 0x12d1
idProduct: 0x1001
bInterfaceNumber: 0
bConfigurationValue: 1
```

I hope I got that right. You should be able to confirm by running `ioreg -c IOUSBInterface` in the Terminal while the device is plugged in. This will show you all USB interfaces' properties in the system in OSX's format, and you should be able to pick out the one for your modem and make sure those properties match the ones I've given.

**Driver class and bundle ID**

In addition to the matching criteria, your I/O Kit personality dictionary in the info.plist needs to specify the (C++) class of which an instance should be created to drive the matched device, along with the bundle ID of the kext that contains it.

The problem now is, what driver to use. I don't know much about CDC-ACM devices, but as far as I can tell, they consist of a control and a data interface. The drivers for this appear to be

```
/System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBCDCACMControl.kext
/System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBCDCACMData.kext
```

respectively, on OSX. Each of these seem to assume they have full control over a USB interface - it seems that most devices split the control and data endpoints over 2 separate interfaces. In your case, you have only one. Technically, multiple drivers can match a service, by using different match categories. But I can't guarantee that the CDC-ACM data and control drivers will be happy with this. You can try…

To do so, you'll actually need two I/O kit personality dictionaries, with the same matching criteria, but one of them should have a non-default `IOMatchCategory`, e.g. the relevant driver bundle ID.

So try something like this:

```
<key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
<dict>
    <key>AppleUSBCDCACMControl</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCACMControl</string>
        <key>IOClass</key>
        <string>AppleUSBCDCACMControl</string>
        <key>IOProviderClass</key>
        <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
        <key>idVendor</key>
        <integer>4817</integer>
        <key>idProduct</key>
        <integer>4097</integer>
        <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>IOMatchCategory</key>
        <string>com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCACMControl</string>
    </dict>
    <key>AppleUSBCDCACMData</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDCACMData</string>
        <key>IOClass</key>
        <string>AppleUSBCDCACMData</string>
        <key>IOProviderClass</key>
        <string>IOUSBInterface</string>
        <key>IOUserClientClass</key>
        <string>AppleUSBCDCACMDataUserClient</string>
        <key>InputBuffers</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>OutputBuffers</key>
        <integer>16</integer>
        <key>idVendor</key>
        <integer>4817</integer>
        <key>idProduct</key>
        <integer>4097</integer>
        <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**Codeless kext info.plist**

As you already have a kext that kextutil appears to like, you've probably got this right already: codeless kexts must:

- Have an empty `OSBundleLibraries` property.
- Not have an `CFBundleExecutable` property.

**Kext signing**

On OSX 10.10 and 10.11, all kexts, including codeless ones, must be signed. On 10.9 they can be unsigned if they reside in `/System/Library/Extensions`, and on 10.10 they can be unsigned if the kernel option `kext-dev-mode=1` is set. You need a special kext signing addition to your Developer Id certificate from Apple in order to sign kexts.

**Loading and Debugging**

Kexts in /System/Library/Extensions (writable until 10.10) or /Library/Extensions (10.9+) will be matched automatically on boot or device hot-plug. They can also be loaded manually from outside those locations with `kextutil`.

Loaded kext binaries are listed in `kextstat`'s output. Codeless kexts don't have binaries and thus don't show up. The bundle containing the driver code, as specified in the I/O Kit Personality's CFBundleIdentifier will show up if it is active, however.

To see what is happening with your specific device, use the `ioreg` command line tool or the GUI tools IORegistryExplorer (from Apple's Hardware I/O Tools bundle) or IOJones (open source).

**Final thoughts**

Given the CDC-ACM Control/Data split, you might not be able to get things working with just a codeless kext. You may need to look deeper into how Apple's drivers work and possibly override some of their behaviour in your own kext so that they find the correct end points. Good luck!

Comment: One thing... On 10.11, I see /S/L/E/AppleUSBCDC.kext, /S/L/E/AppleUSBACM.kext, and others for ECM, EEM, and even NCM and WCM (!!!). Also, I don't know if Apple's drivers split between control and data anymore, as sources are not up yet for 10.11. Also, wondering now why no QMI or MBIM yet, and where are ECM/NCM/WCM originally meant to be deployed.

Comment: Oops, my wrong. Still two classes for control and data, just in one executable.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm still on 10.10.5 on my main MBP, I didn't realise they'd changed things around in 10.11. But it sounds like everything else still stands. Good luck getting the 2 drivers to work with just the one interface!

Comment: The kext gets loaded successfully, but the device is not matched. There is no logging IOUSBFamily for anything newer than 10.9.4.

Comment: Added Info.plist. Seems like I fail now to match the device after all (the CDC drivers are not even loaded). According to Apple docs, they should match (idVendor + idProduct + bcdDevice + bConfigurationValue + bInterfaceNumber). Can it be that class, subclass, and protocol are all 255 (thus maybe requiring other keys, or I read it wrong)?

Comment: I have accepted the answer as it is the best codeless kext guide I've read so far; however, I haven't yet solved the problem of matching my device to the driver. Guess maybe Apple will release some means to debug USB connection for 10.11 some time.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't got around to looking at your issue closer yet. I suggest splitting your problem in 2: (1) solving the matching issue and (2) getting the relevant driver to load. For (1), try using an IOClass of IOService in your IOKit personalities. If your matching dictionary is good, you should see an IOService client on your device for each match category. For (2), if switching to the actual driver class makes things stop working, you'll need to dig deeper, but at least you'll have eliminated the matching side as the source of your problems.